# Use ui:repeat variable in c:if statement

Tags: jsf, if-statement, jsf-2, jstl, uirepeat

I am trying to use a c:if statement inside a ui:repeat tag.
However U cannot get the value of course.days while inside the if tag. It just always evaluates to empty.

```
    <div id="schedule_wrapper">
        <ui:repeat value="#{schedule.courses}" var="course">                
            <div class="course">
                <b>#{course.shortTitle}</b> : #{course.subjectCode} #{course.courseNumber}-#{course.section}<br /> 
                #{course.roomCode} #{course.buildingName} <br />
                <c:if test="${not empty course.days}">
                    #{course.days} : #{course.startTime} - #{course.endTime}
                </c:if>                                         
            </div>
        </ui:repeat>
    </div>
```

Any ideas how I can use the course.days variable inside the if statement?
Or an alternate way to achieve the same thing...
All of the other course.xxxxx value as pulling their values in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use  inside your  using a rendered to check your condition.
rendered="#{not empty course.days}" or #{course.days > 0} if days is a Integer

```
<div id="schedule_wrapper">
    <ui:repeat value="#{schedule.courses}" var="course">                
        <div class="course">
            <b>#{course.shortTitle}</b> : #{course.subjectCode} #{course.courseNumber}-#{course.section}<br /> 
            #{course.roomCode} #{course.buildingName} <br />
            **<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty course.days}">
                #{course.days} : #{course.startTime} - #{course.endTime}
            </ui:fragment>**                                        
        </div>
    </ui:repeat>
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate way to achieve this.
Instead of:

```
<c:if test="${not empty course.days}">
    #{course.days} : #{course.startTime} - #{course.endTime}
</c:if>
```

I used:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty course.days}">
    #{course.days} : #{course.startTime} - #{course.endTime}
</h:panelGroup>
```

I am still interested if this is possible with an if statement.